# Image not 100% width and doesn't extend properly when I zoom out

Tags: html, css, image, width

I have a bar at the bottom of the website for certain content.  The problem is that it's currently not extending (width) to cover the entire screen despite the code to do so.

HTML is rather basic

```
<div class="bottom-ulity">
other content goes here
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bottom-ulity {
    height     : 57px;
    width      : 100%;
    right      : 0;
    position   : fixed;
    bottom     : 0;
    background : url('../images/inner-show-text.png') repeat-x left top;
    z-index    : 1000;
}
```

I have tried giving a min-width: 100%, tried adding the 2046px as min-width.  I looked at some other pages and saw recommendations with "background-size: 100%" and "background-size: cover".  Both of these lines of code give the same result, it makes the image itself extend properly however it loses all its effects such as the gradient and instead gives me a basic gray color.

I tried deleting all the divs inside to see if the code inside was causing this, but that wasn't the case either.  When I added "background-repeat: no-repeat;", I noticed that the image would only show up once and it wasn't extending at all, leaving a massive gaping hole on where the bar is supposed to be (zoomed out far enough obviously).

Here's an image showing the issue:
[image]

Comment: Can you please link the website so we can view it?

Comment: It isn't up yet.  It's local only at the moment.

Comment: It's hard to help you without being able to see the site myself. Let us know when it's live and I'm sure we will be able to help then.

Comment: I appreciate the help Saunders but I have to get this task fixed before then, which will be in two weeks.  The weird issue is that I deleted everything inside the bar and the problem still persisted, so my guess is it's the code in bar itself causing the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I found a hack for the problem, at least one that will be good enough temporarily. I decided to add `background-size: 100%`
to the css which seemed to fix the problem until I started to zoom in.  While the image itself was one and extended 100% in width as it should have, it would start to move up the screen despite being a fixed position with bottom and right set at 0.  What I decided was to add

```
background-size: 200%;
```

This fixed the issue though that border that is part of the image obviously is twice as big at the moment, which means while it works perfectly, the border being twice as thick it doesn't quite as elegant.

UPDATE: A fix to that solution is simply lowering the px that will be duplicated if the img allows in half.  Since the background-size is at 200%, it means everything is multiplied.  So if you have a different % to fix a similar issue, keep in mind how many pixels you had before making changes.